# Jekyll routing and Collection

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I started building my blog with Jekyll, i have the following structure:

- About.md
- index.md
- _posts

  - article1.md
  - article2.md
- other files...

how should I set my _config.yml file so I show the articles as group? I didn't fully understand how the navigation works!

Here what i have in the config file about navigation

```
paginate:      10
paginate_path: '/:num/'

menu:
  - title: Blog
    url: /

  - title: About
    url: /about
```